# How to deal with NaN values when plotting a boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I am using matplotlib to plot a box figure but there are some missing values (NaN). Then I found it doesn't display the box figure within the columns having NaN values.
Do you know how to solve this problem?
Here are the codes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#==============================================================================
# open data
#==============================================================================
filename='C:\\Users\\liren\\OneDrive\\Data\\DATA in the first field-final\\ks.csv'

AllData=np.genfromtxt(filename,delimiter=";",skip_header=0,dtype='str')

TreatmentCode = AllData[1:,0]
RepCode = AllData[1:,1]
KsData= AllData[1:,2:].astype('float')
DepthHeader = AllData[0,2:].astype('float')
TreatmentUnique = np.unique(TreatmentCode)[[3,1,4,2,8,6,9,7,0,5,10],]
nT = TreatmentUnique.size#nT=number of treatments
#nD=number of deepth;nR=numbers of replications;nT=number of treatments;iT=iterms of treatments
nD = 5
nR = 6
KsData_3D = np.zeros((nT,nD,nR)) 

for iT in range(nT):
    Treatment = TreatmentUnique[iT]

    TreatmentFilter = TreatmentCode == Treatment

    KsData_Filtered = KsData[TreatmentFilter,:]
    
    KsData_3D[iT,:,:] = KsData_Filtered.transpose()iD = 4
                      
fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.boxplot(KsData_3D[:,iD,:].transpose())
ax.set_xticks(range(1,nT+1))
ax.set_xticklabels(TreatmentUnique)
ax.set_title(DepthHeader[iD])
```

Here is the final figure and some of the treatments are missing in the box.

[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can remove the `NaN`s from the data first, then plot the filtered data.

To do that, you can first find the `NaN`s using [`np.isnan(data)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html), then perform the bitwise inversion of that Boolean array using the [`~`: bitwise inversion operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions). Use that to index the data array, and you filter out the `NaN`s.

```
filtered_data = data[~np.isnan(data)]
```

In a complete example (adapted from [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pyplots/boxplot_demo_pyplot.html))

**Tested in `python 3.10`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`, `numpy 1.21.5`, `pandas 1.4.2`**

#### For 1D data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# fake up some data
np.random.seed(2022)  # so the same data is created each time
spread = np.random.rand(50) * 100
center = np.ones(25) * 50
flier_high = np.random.rand(10) * 100 + 100
flier_low = np.random.rand(10) * -100
data = np.concatenate((spread, center, flier_high, flier_low), 0)

# Add a NaN
data[40] = np.NaN

# Filter data using np.isnan
filtered_data = data[~np.isnan(data)]

# basic plot
plt.boxplot(filtered_data)

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### For 2D data:

For 2D data, you can't simply use the mask above, since then each column of the data array would have a different length. Instead, we can create a list, with each item in the list being the filtered data for each column of the data array.

A list comprehension can do this in one line: `[d[m] for d, m in zip(data.T, mask.T)]`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# fake up some data
np.random.seed(2022)  # so the same data is created each time
spread = np.random.rand(50) * 100
center = np.ones(25) * 50
flier_high = np.random.rand(10) * 100 + 100
flier_low = np.random.rand(10) * -100
data = np.concatenate((spread, center, flier_high, flier_low), 0)

data = np.column_stack((data, data * 2., data + 20.))

# Add a NaN
data[30, 0] = np.NaN
data[20, 1] = np.NaN

# Filter data using np.isnan
mask = ~np.isnan(data)
filtered_data = [d[m] for d, m in zip(data.T, mask.T)]

# basic plot
plt.boxplot(filtered_data)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to extend this to 3 or more dimensions, but you get the idea.

---

The solution above is how to do this using `matplotlib` alone. Other alternatives (that use `matplotlib` under the hood) are available that have this behaviour built in, so no need to filter the data yourself.

1. Use `seaborn`, which is a high-level API for `matplotlib`. [`seaborn.boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) filters `NaN` under the hood.

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.boxplot(data=data)
```

### 1D

[image]

### 2D

[image]

---

2. Use `pandas`. `NaN` is also ignored if plotting from [`df.plot(kind='box')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) for `pandas`, which uses `matplotlib` as the default plotting backend.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.plot(kind='box')
```

### 1D

[image]

### 2D

[image]

Comment: Excellent summary! One question though. In the beginning instead of the isnan and the bitwise inversion, wouldn't it be simpler to use `dropna()`?