# boxplot structure disappears when pandas contains nan

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, nan, boxplot

I'm trying to plot a boxplot with a dataset (in form of a pandas) containing `nan` (introduced with `df.iloc[2,2] = np.nan`).

Howver the boxplot structure disappears for the column containing nan

Here is the plot [image: plot]

Here is he code (inspired from [this website](https://towardsdatascience.com/scattered-boxplots-graphing-experimental-results-with-matplotlib-seaborn-and-pandas-81f9fa8a1801)):

```
# https://towardsdatascience.com/scattered-boxplots-graphing-experimental-results-with-matplotlib-seaborn-and-pandas-81f9fa8a1801

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pdb
dataset = np.random.default_rng().uniform(60,95,(20,4))
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns=['data1','data2','data3','data4'])
df.head()
df.iloc[2,2] = np.nan

for n in range(1,df.columns.shape[0]+1):
    df.rename(columns={f"data{n}": f"Experiment {n}"}, inplace=True)
vals, names, xs = [],[],[]
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
  vals.append(df[col].values)
  names.append(col)
  xs.append(np.random.normal(i + 1, 0.04, df[col].values.shape[0])) 

plt.boxplot(vals, labels=names)
palette = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y']
for x, val, c in zip(xs, vals, palette):
  plt.scatter(x, val, alpha=0.4, color=c)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with NaN value when plot boxplot using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305873/how-to-deal-with-nan-value-when-plot-boxplot-using-python)

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @RoseGod